# Reload a Property from a Camel Route without stopping it

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to figure out a way to update dynamically a property (from a PropertyComponent) without stopping the Camel Route:
Here's an example of it:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
        CamelContext ctx = super.getContext();
        PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
        pc.setLocation("/tmp/apache-deltaspike.properties");
        ctx.addComponent("properties", pc);

        // Logs Hello World every 2000 milliseconds
        from("timer://myEapTimer?fixedRate=true&period=2000")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "com.sample.route", "{{customProperty}}")
            .to("log:HelloWorldLog?level=INFO");

}
```

The external Property file contains the message to be printed every time the Timer fires. I'd need to find a way to let the Route reload the Property file without stopping it.
BTW I'm using Apache Camel 2.17.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, the `{{xxx}}` is resolved only once when the route is starting up.

You can use a Java bean where you can load the properties file yourself and get the value and do the logging there.

Or you can call the Java bean with bean parameter binding and have the properties value injected. But you then also need to configure the properties component to not use caching etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help Claus!